# How to get an up to date PhD title in Cloud Computing Security?

Tags: advisor, supervision, research-topic, thesis-committee

I have got a PhD scholarship in Cloud Computing Security, and its about one year am doing research and literature review in that field. However, I haven't reached any point to start with, I'm a little depressed with that. The problem is my supervisor cannot guide me and he doesn't has a very good background in that field and I can't ask for alternative or second supervisor, because the university rule doesn't allows that.

Any advice on how to choose a topic, as I required to publish two papers in high impact factor (Thomson Reuters) journals before submitting my dissertation?

Comment: If you supervisor cannot supervise you, then you need to change supervisor. The university rule must be broken. (Actually, the rules probably define ways to change supervisors, because the university will surely have made such a change previously.)

Comment: @user2768 thanks for your reply, I have tried that several times. Now I'm trying to depend on myself..

Comment: Is there a more senior researcher at your university who does know the field? If so, even if you can't have a second supervisor (and note that rules like this can often be bent for good reason), might they be willing to help you unofficially?

Comment: What does "up to date PhD title" mean?

Comment: @Flyto thanks for your reply, there were two researchers, unfortunately currently they are not available at the university.

Comment: @AzorAhai, I mean current hot research topics

Comment: @JavaCrawler By "PhD" title did you mean something like "dissertation title"?

Comment: Dear @AzorAhai, I'm planning to work on Cloud Computing Security, and I'm planning to work on a much detailed area.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by what  you mean by "up-to-date PhD title"

Comment: @AzorAhai, I mean which area of cloud computing security is better to do research on.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, I hope. One is choosing a new topic that your supervisor is more familiar with. He or she is the one to help you with that, so you need to have a discussion about it.

However, while your supervisor isn't familiar with the topic you have, he should be familiar with how to do research and to get quickly to the edge of the known world in any given (similar) field. So he may be able to help you find the resources you need and even respond intelligently to your questions and concerns. The only thing that he can't help you with is specific topical questions (facts and techniques). But he can help you find the places in which you can learn that.

Even if he were more up to date in the field, you would still need to read a lot of papers and work to understand them and the remaining work to be done.

At some point every doctoral student needs to surpass the understanding of their professor. That doesn't mean the professor is of no use anymore, it is just the specific topic that you are then able to teach them, rather than the other way round.

Comment: many thanks for your recommendation, I may think about that way.